# Sumarize the occurrence number of multiple columns values as a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering that I have a data frame with the following structure:

```
    Symbol   CS
0     A1    MSI
1     A2    MSI
2     A3    GS
3     A2    EBV
4     A2    CIN
5     A1    GS    
6     A2    MSI
...
```

I would like to have a dataframe that categorizes the column CS as the header and the column Symbol as the index. The values would be the occurrence of each symbol by the CS type. As an example, the output expected from the above dataframe would be:

```
    MSI   EBV   CIN   GS
A1   1     0     0    1
A2   2     1     1    0
A3   0     0     0    1
```

What would be the best efficient approach to resolve this particular case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.Symbol,df.CS)
Out[862]: 
CS      CIN  EBV  GS  MSI
Symbol                   
A1        0    0   1    1
A2        1    1   0    2
A3        0    0   1    0
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats really efficient and fast!

Comment: Wen is a Python Guru.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `pd.value_counts` followed by `pd.pivot_table`.

**Edit:** But really you should use [@Wen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49961921/9209546).

```
counts = df.groupby('Symbol')['CS'].apply(pd.value_counts).reset_index()

res = counts.pivot_table(index='Symbol', columns='level_1', values='CS',
                         fill_value=0, aggfunc=lambda x: x)

print(res)

# level_1  CIN  EBV  GS  MSI
# Symbol                    
# A1         0    0   1    1
# A2         1    1   0    2
# A3         0    0   1    0
```

Comment: In this particular case, the crosstab worked just fine! But thank you anyway!

Comment: @JoãoFernandes, Please accept Wen's answer (green tick on left) - his is much better!